# Ink File Picker define dynamic bucket name for storing files on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, asp.net-mvc-5, filepicker.io

In the widget part of Ink File Picker. How can I dynamically declare the bucket name to store the file in that bucket? I read the documentation in for it under https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/web/#widgets
but it was not mentioned.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards
Vishal

Answer (score 0):

The bucket (or container, as they use) setting is: **data-fp-store-container**.

It is also the same concept in the pickAndStore API.

Comment: *My issue I am trying to figure out is how to specify a different key for each bucket/container.